# How to group bag in pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

First I have data and I group

```
A = LOAD './test.txt' USING PigStorage(' ') AS (id:int, time:int, value:float);

B = GROUP A BY time;
```

For example result I have structure like this.

```
1001    {(1,1001,0.2),(3,1001,0.3),(2,1001,0.3),(4,1001,0.6)}   
1002    {(2,1002,0.5),(1,1002,0.3),(3,1002,0.1),(4,1002,0.6)}  
1003    {(4,1003,0.2),(1,1003,0.8),(2,1003,0.4),(3,1003,0.5)}
```

But I want

```
1001     {(1,1001,0.2),(2,1001,0.3),(3,1001,0.3),(4,1001,0.6)}
1002     {(1,1002,0.3),(2,1002,0.5),(3,1002,0.1),(4,1002,0.6)}   
1003     {(1,1003,0.8),(2,1003,0.4),(3,1003,0.5),(4,1003,0.2)}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use NESTED FOREACH

```
C = FOREACH B {
          sort_by_id = ORDER A BY id;
          GENERATE group, sort_by_id ;
              };
```

Comment: Thank you, I found something like sorted = ORDER A by $0 ASC;.